# special characters in facebook canvas

Tags: php, utf-8, facebook-php-sdk, html-encode

im having problems with special characters in the facebook canvas.

Im retreiving the users friends who haven't installed the app and displaying them. However, when i display them, the special chars appear as if they where encoded differently.

For example, á appears as Ã¡, é as Ã© and so on.

Iv tried some things that haven't worked:

```
<? 
$search=array('Ã', 'Ã¡', 'Ã©','Ã­','Ã³','Ãº','Ã±');
$replace=array('&Aacute;', '&aacute;','&eacute;','&iacute;','&oacute;','&uacute;','&nacute;',);

echo str_replace($search,$replace, $friend_name) ?>

<? echo htmlentities($friend_name) ?>
```

some more info: Im working with facebook's php sdk, and set mete tag:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

Thanks

EDIT: applied utf8_decode() and the problem was solved. Is there anyway of solving the problem without this function?

Comment: In wich encoding are you retrieving the users friends? And into which encoding do you convert it then? It looks like you convert them from UTF-8 by claiming it's latin-1 into UTF-8 again. Don't do that and you should be fine.

Comment: I Just retreive the user list with the php sdk, by calling the Graph API ($facebook->api('/me/friends')). Im Always working in UTF-8

Answer (score 1):

Smells like a character encoding issue (UTF, cp1252, etc) as opposed to an escaping issue (`\htmlspecialchars`). Check your source and destination encodings; they're probably mismatched.

By the way, it's worth mentioning that the default internal encoding for PHP changed to UTF-8 as of version 5.4, so you may also be running into bugs caused by version mismatches.

Comment: @Dan Stern: You commented above that you always use UTF-8, so technically, you don't run into any issues here. So either the names consist of the characters you want to remove (and therefore you would destroy the names) -or- the information you provided (always UTF-8) is incorrect. I'd say the latter, so please verify which input is not UTF-8 or is not that that it is because of you make it UTF-8. Just check all input encodings.

Answer (score 0):

You should encode that document UTF-8. It depends on the editor you use the way it encodes. In notepad++ there is a encoding tab and you should use UTF-8 without BOM. This fixed my problem with facebook.

Even though you set the meta tag it won't be enough, you should encode your document UTF-8. If you do this, it will save you from having to encode/decode most similar things.